# Find and select an element based on its datum, not CSS selector with D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Is it possible to do something like:

```
d3.select('rect', function(d, i){ return d.status === 'enabled' })
```

So to find the element I use not CSS selectors, but datum properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.filter()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#filter):

```
d3.selectAll('rect').filter(function(d, i) { return d.status === 'enabled' });
```

Comment: Yup, that was my solution already, thanks anyway for making clear there is no built-in way! Though, it should be a slightly modified: `d3.selectAll('rect')[0].filter(function(d, i) { return d.status === 'enabled' });`

Comment: You don't need the `[0]`. If you add that, you're working on Javascript arrays instead of D3 selections which you probably don't want.

Comment: As far as I see, `.filter()` method is default JS one, not from D3?

Comment: there's `.filter()` on selections: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#filter

Comment: I initially used `.filter()` from JS, but as D3 has its own filter method, I will use it. Thanks!